# How to tell magento that I use different theme directory?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm just a newbie with magento. I downloaded a module created by someone and I want to modify it. I have a problem when I change theme directory. Magento always reads it to older directory. It has something to do with product view.

I try to edit the, let's say, abcd.xml file inside layout folder from

```
<reference name='product.info'>
   <action method='setTemplate'><template>histheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name='product.info.addtocart'>
    <action method='setTemplate'><template>histheme/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

to something line this

```
<reference name='product.info'>
   <action method='setTemplate'><template>default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name='product.info.addtocart'>
   <action method='setTemplate'><template>default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

But it doesn't work!! When I change it like the above, the product view part is just blank. Please, tell me what should I do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The path you set for the templates are relative to the theme directory.
If you want a different theme for the products, you can just set it in the backend for that specific product.

Comment: actually I don't intend to set different theme for specific product. What I want to do is telling magento that I'm calling the same file, _view_ and _addtocart.phtm_ but in different directory

Comment: then why don put your file in the current theme?

Comment: I already put the file on the current theme, but magento keeps on calling the old one, which is I don't understand